# Why doesn't SharePoint show other copies?

Tags: sharepoint-online

[image: SharePoint13 Copy]

Why doesn't SharePoint 13 display the other copies icon when I try and copy the document a third time?

Comment: Do you mean versions of document ?

Comment: I'm not sure. I copied one document and saved it in another library.

Comment: Then that will not shown here, there is no linking between those

Answer (score 0):

It's not shown here , To get the other copies Icons of a specific document, you should  do the following

- At the document that has been copied via `Sent To` > Click on `...` then `...` select View Properties.

[image]

- From the above ribbon > Click on Manage Copies.

[image]

- Here you can get all copies of this document with its path.

[image]